# Clicking on thumbnail images need to display the slider images using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having thumbnail images on my gallery page whenever user clicks on the thumbnail images it should display the slider images which should be slided automatically.I have tried with some examples posted in google but it didn't work .Here is my code.

[**Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/k2ho4m9d/2/) is my fiddle link

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="image1">
  <img src="images/image01.jpg" class="img-responsive">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img class="first-slide" src="images/Image30.jpg" alt="First Slide">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img class="second-slide" src="images/Image14.jpg" alt="second Slide">
      </div>

    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="image2">
  <img src="images/image13.jpg" class="img-responsive">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

      <div class="item active">
        <img class="third-slide" src="images/Image29.jpg" alt="third Slide">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img class="third-slide" src="images/Image32.jpg" alt="third Slide">
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

In jsfiddle i have added some sample images for clarification

Comment: You say they should slide automatically and they do. **What exactly is your issue/question?** - While you have not stated/asked it, I do see and issue in your code where both carousels have the same `id` which is going move the first match of the `id` found only no matter which carousel you interact with. Though you haven;t specified if that is your issue... is it?

Comment: @Nope First of all it should not show the slider when i open the gallery page it should show only the thumbnail images once i click on thumbnail image then only it should display those slider images

Comment: Nice @user6728960 - You should edit your question and add that info to the question, it is important to know or we don't know what to fix.

Comment: @Nope edited my question

Comment: anyone can help me out this one